# How to open new activity onClick on marquee text?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have marquee displaying names of friends from array list.I want to open new activity on click on any name of my friend.

I have done following to display array list in marquee

```
tv.setText("");
    for(int i=0;i<c_name.size();i++){
        tv.append(c_name.get(i)+" | ");
    }

    tv.setSelected(true);
```

I got marquee like this

Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 | Name 4 | ....

Now i want to open new activity on click on name. I know how to open new activity when used in ListView but dont have any idea for marquee.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Thanks & onward i will take care of that.And please check my updated question.

Comment: I am get stuck here from last 2day. Please help me.

Comment: Well, I don't actually develop for Android, so I can't really help you. Some questions are unlucky, and can't find an expert soon enough. I suggest two things: 1) Keep editing and adding details, this will keep moving the question up, and help potential answerers, and 2) if you really need help right away, research it yourself/ask help somewhere else, and once you have an answer, post it here for everyone else. Good luck! :)